# Retrieve target of existing Symbolic Link folder in Windows

Tags: windows, server, windows-server-2008, mklink

It may seem a very noob to a few but I am trying to retrieve the the target of an existing symbolic link folder in Windows. I checked the properties of this link but nothing was displayed. How can I do it?

Edit: issue is in Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the information about the linked "target" by using the dir command. I did the following:

1. Changed the directory to the parent of symbolic link folder in Command Prompt.
2. Used the **dir** command

The file type of the symbolic link was displayed as **`<<Junction>>`** and the target location was displayed in the very next column.

*edit:*
This problem is in Windows Server 2008.